# SSH and firewall settings I can't find

Tags: centos, iptables, ssh

I'm having trouble gaining SSH access to my new server. I currently have one server set up working the way I want it to, and I'm trying to get a different one to work the same way. I've copied my users files (/etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, /etc/group, and /etc/gshadow) and the /home folders (including /home/*/.ssh). I even added a new user (testuser) on the new machine and am using that to test the ssh settings. Both /etc/ssh/sshd_config and 
/etc/ssh/ssh_config are the same, as are the iptables rules.

When I try to use PuTTY to log in to the new server using a copy of the settings from the old server (except for address, of course) I get an error:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available

And in the /var/log/secure file I get the line:

> sshd[6562]: Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 14: No supported authentication methods available

Both old and new server are running centOS

Where else can I find configurations that might be off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like a firewall/ipteables issue. More likely you have either broken your passwd/shadow config (perhaps the new machine uses a different password hashing) or ssh is configured to allow key authentication only, not password.

Comment: Both the old and new servers use only key authentication. The passwd/shadow files were copied as-is, and then just to be sure I did `useradd tempuser` and copied the .ssh folder from my old home directory to this directory. I copied /etc/ssh/sshd_config from the old machine to the new, and ran `service sshd restart`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Permissions on the /home/username/.ssh/ directory and files in it?

Comment: It was permissions!!!! Thank you! I guess when I copied everything I was root, so I went through and chowned everything back to what it needed to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe PAM authentication settings differ? Look in `/etc/pam.d/` and `/etc/security/`.